# Is there a good bound for this double exponential recursion?

Tags: co.combinatorics, recurrences

Denote when $k>2m$ $$f_k(2m)=\sum_{i=1,i\geq1}^m\binom{2m}{i}f_k(i)f_k(2m-i)$$
$$f_k(2m+1)=\sum_{i=1,i\geq1}^m\binom{2m+1}{i}f_k(i)f_k(2m+1-i)$$

$$f_k(0)=1.$$
$$f_k(1)=k.$$

1. What is a good bound for $f_{2^{n+1}}(2^{n})$?
2. How does it compare with $\binom{2^{n+1}}{2^n}$? Is $f_{2^{n+1}}(2^{n})>\binom{2^{n+1}}{2^n}$?

Comment: Your rules do not seem to work properly.  They start with $f(0)=f(0)$, then $f(1)=f(0)f(1)$, then $f(2)=f(0)f(2)+2f(1)^2$, which does not determine $f(0)$, $f(1)$ and $f(2)$.  Probably your equations should be adjusted slightly.

Comment: What about $f(1)$?

Comment: So now, $f(k,m)=k^mf(1,m)$, hence $f(2^{n+1},2^n)\ge2^{(n+1)2^n}\ge2^{2^{n+1}}>\binom{2^{n+1}}{2^n}$.

Comment: Then do define it for $m>1$. The identity follows by trivial induction on $m$.

Comment: Experimentally, $f(k,n)=n!k^n$  [A000992](http://oeis.org/A000992)(n)

Comment: Look, let $g(k,n)=f(k,n)/n!$, then$$g(k,n)=\sum_{2i\le n}g(k,i)g(k,n-i)$$

Comment: I will try to expand in an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For brevity, rewrite the recursion as$$f_k(n)=\sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant\frac n2}\binom nif_k(i)f_k(n-i).$$Now divide it by $n!k^n$ and rewrite like this:$$\frac{f_k(n)}{n!k^n}=\frac1{n!}\sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant\frac n2}\binom nii!(n-i)!\frac{f_k(i)}{i!k^i}\frac{f_k(n-i)}{(n-i)!k^{n-i}}.$$
It follows that for$$g_k(n):=\frac{f_k(n)}{n!k^n}$$we get$$g_k(n)=\sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant\frac n2}g_k(i)g_k(n-i),$$and $g_k(1)=1$ (in particular $g_k(n)$ does not depend on $k$).

This is the recursion for [A000992](http://oeis.org/A000992) (number of (unlabeled, rooted) ordered trees on $n-1$ vertices in which all outdegrees are $\leqslant2$ and, for each vertex of outdegree $2$, the sizes of its two subtrees are weakly increasing left to right ($n\geqslant2$)). That page contains some information about these numbers.

Comment: So the growth of $g_k(n)$ is $\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}$?

Comment: The fraction $\frac12$ comes from 'half-catalans' is 'catalan' by 2.

Comment: $\log(g(n))/\log(\textrm{Catalan}_n)$ seems to be unbounded